C free() on Ubuntu VM, a question regarding heap memory
A simple program to allocate and free heap memory:
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *b1, *b2, *b3, *b4, *b_large;
    b1 = malloc(8);
    memset(b1, 0xaa, 8);
    b2= malloc(16);
    memset(b2, 0xbb, 16);
    b3 = malloc(25);
    memset(b3, 0xcc, 25);
    b4= malloc(1000);
    memset(b4, 0xdd, 1000);
    free(b1);
    free(b2);
    free(b3);
    free(b4);

Before first free():
(gdb) x/20gx  0x555555559290 
0x555555559290: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000021
0x5555555592a0: 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  0x0000000000000000
0x5555555592b0: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000021
0x5555555592c0: 0xbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb  0xbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
0x5555555592d0: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000031
0x5555555592e0: 0xcccccccccccccccc  0xcccccccccccccccc
0x5555555592f0: 0xcccccccccccccccc  0x00000000000000cc
0x555555559300: 0x0000000000000000  0x00000000000003f1
0x555555559310: 0xdddddddddddddddd  0xdddddddddddddddd
0x555555559320: 0xdddddddddddddddd  0xdddddddddddddddd

And after first free():
(gdb) x/20gx  0x555555559290 
0x555555559290: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000021
0x5555555592a0: 0x0000000555555559  0xd13e7903c502febc
0x5555555592b0: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000021
0x5555555592c0: 0xbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb  0xbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
0x5555555592d0: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000031
0x5555555592e0: 0xcccccccccccccccc  0xcccccccccccccccc
0x5555555592f0: 0xcccccccccccccccc  0x00000000000000cc
0x555555559300: 0x0000000000000000  0x00000000000003f1
0x555555559310: 0xdddddddddddddddd  0xdddddddddddddddd
0x555555559320: 0xdddddddddddddddd  0xdddddddddddddddd

I was expecting to see readable forward and back pointers in the second line of memory, and
in the third line 0x20 in both 8-bytes segments.
Can anyone explain why the free() function would behave in this way?

Why do you expect anything in particular? What happens to the memory that's freed is not specified by the language.

The free() function isn't guaranteed to change anything.  All free() does is make that memory available to subsequent malloc, calloc, etc. calls.  That is a good thing that free() works this way, as why would a C programmer want cycles wasted on free() changing memory locations?

Why do you expect it?

If this is just curiosity, then please say so in the question. Otherwise if you have an actual problem that you're trying to get help with, then please ask about it directly instead.

@PaulMcKenzie What's surprising is that it does change the memory.

@Barmar -- Could be that the build being run is unoptimized?

@PaulMcKenzie Why would unoptimized free() modify the memory? This seems more like they're using a debugging malloc that uses this to detect double frees.

Hi Barmar, thanks. Because the glib malloc.c notes state the that the two pointers overwrite the first line of data, and that the header  incorporates the previous chunk size and drops the P flag.

As this is Ubuntu and, therefore, presumably glibc, one has to bear in mind that glibc uses a caching allocator, i.e. not every malloc results in a call to the OS to get more memory, and not every free gives the memory back to the OS. Instead, it maintains a pool of pre-allocated memory out of which it attempts to satisfy program requirements, to speed things up. Looking at the source code it's clear that the implementation of free() tags freed memory to indicate that it now belongs to glibc and not the application, and can therefore re-use it for more malloc() calls. All in the name of speed.

Hi Bazza, thanks for this, do you happen to know what the data in the second line might be then?

@bazza That's how most malloc implementations have worked for ages, there's nothing special about glibc.

where does the 0x555555559290 address come from?

Hi yano, it's 16 bytes less than the b1 pointer, showing the first header

@barmar glibc wasn't even the first, but it's a technique that is far from being ubiquitous as some platforms prefer the surity derived from getting allocations from the OS every time. glibc's approach is fast, but more prone to memory faults going undiscovered. For example, I've got flow graphs for GNU Radio (predefined blobs of C++ strung together with Python) that work just fine on Linux, but the exact same code built and run on FreeBSD (which uses a different allocator) segfaults. Ergo, there's memory errors in GNU Radio that no one is finding because most run it on Linux/glibc...

@rdre8 see Marco Bonelli's answer

@Barmar, I was somewhat amused by the rise of caching allocators because for code that I cared about I'd been doing something similar in application source code for years. The motivation was primarily to limit the consumption of Translate Lookaside Buffers (on PowerPC). By allocating all my application's memory in one malloc() and then dividing that up in my source code, one could avoid the TLB in the CPUs getting hammered inside DSP loops that had to be fast and realtime. Fortunately with such code the memory allocations are all done before the hot loop, so it wasn't very complicated to do.

Notably gcc can and will optimize out some of these malloc calls entirely if you have optimizations enabled.

@bazza AFAIK, it's the oldest technique, since originally Unix only had one way to get memory from the OS, and it was sbrk(). This could only extend/shrink the data segment at one end, so the only time free() could return the memory was if you happened to be freeing an allocation at that end. Alternatives only became available when mmap() was added (in BSD, I think), but few malloc() implementations took advantage of this.

@Barmar I didn't know that - thanks very much!. I started using other POSIX-like OSes a long time ago (e.g. VxWorks), which always and only had simple allocators that dealt directly with the OS every time (there was less penalty in an RTOS like VxWorks). I'd not realised that old Unixes hadn't implemented today's understanding of malloc() and free(). It reminds me of how many OSes didn't implement select(), or threads, until quite late on into the early 90s.

Assuming you are working with Ubuntu 22.04 and therefore glibc 2.36.
Modern heap allocators nowadays are... quite complex, and glibc is a prime example of this. Don't expect to see nice things such as plain pointers that easily.
The seemingly random value you see (0xd13e7903c502febc) is the internal tcache_key. It is indeed a random uintptr_t value initialized once at program startup using getrandom(2) and later inserted into free chunks that are kept in tcache.
The value of tcache_key is inserted into chunks that go in tcache and then checked on free as a simple hardening against double-free. It is removed when a tcache chunk is re-allocated. This was implemented in glibc 2.34. Previously (glibc 2.29-2.33) a fixed value was used instead of tcache_key.
If you are wondering what the "tcache" is, it is a per-thread cache consisting of several buckets. Each bucket is reserved for a given allocation size and holds freed chunks of exactly that size in a singly linked list of at most 7 elements (unless specified differently using glibc tunables env vars) in LIFO order (newly freed chunks are inserted in the head). When a bucket is full, freeing a chunk of that size will not add it to tcache but instead follow the "normal" freeing procedure and end up in one of the normal arena "bins" according to the rather convoluted glibc algorithm.
The pointers to the next chunk in tcache buckets are also mangled on free and unmangled on alloc (as you can see here) through dedicated macros that use the implicit randomness of the mapping (mmap_base) provided by the kernel through ASLR. This is why you don't see a clear pointer in the chunks either.

After free(b1); free(b2); I have the following:
(gdb) x/20gx 0x5555555592a0 - 0x10
0x555555559290: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000021  -- b1
0x5555555592a0: 0x0000000555555559  0xdefa7fb306dd6989
0x5555555592b0: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000021  -- b2
0x5555555592c0: 0x000055500000c7f9  0xdefa7fb306dd6989
0x5555555592d0: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000031  -- b3
0x5555555592e0: 0xcccccccccccccccc  0xcccccccccccccccc
0x5555555592f0: 0xcccccccccccccccc  0x00000000000000cc
0x555555559300: 0x0000000000000000  0x00000000000003f1  -- b4
0x555555559310: 0xdddddddddddddddd  0xdddddddddddddddd
0x555555559320: 0xdddddddddddddddd  0xdddddddddddddddd

On free, both b1 and b2 end up in the same tcache bucket, the smallest one, for size 16 (malloc(8) is rounded up to 16). We have b2 as the head since the list is LIFO.
The tcache looks like this:
{
  counts = {2, 0, 0, 0, ...},
  entries = {0x5555555592c0, 0x0, 0x00, 0x00, ...}
}

As you can see above, 0xdefa7fb306dd6989 is the value of tcache_key. Looking at the free chunk at 0x5555555592c0, its ->next pointer is mangled to 0x000055500000c7f9. The real value can be obtained as:
(0x5555555592c0UL >> 12) ^ 0x55500000c7f9UL == 0x5555555592a0UL

The ->next->next is simply NULL (mangled to 0x0000000555555559).

When you say "I was expecting to see readable forward and back pointers in the second line of memory" you are describing non-tcache behavior of large chunks. Even ignoring/disabling tcache, small enough chunks can also be kept in singly linked lists (fastbins) again up to a certain fixed number (IIRC). It is only for larger sizes that you actually have doubly linked lists where both pointers are used as you expect.
If you want to experiment more, fill tcache first by freeing 7 chunks of the same size or just disable tcache running your program with GLIBC_TUNABLES=glibc.malloc.tcache_max=0, then let the program do some frees and check. To also disable "fast" bins and get the doubly-linked-list behavior you expect on free, set glibc.malloc.mxfast=0 too.
Installing debug symbols from the libc6-dbg package and using the pwndbg GDB plugin, you will have very useful commands to inspect the glibc heap and the various bins. For example:

heap showing all chunks
bins showing the state of arena bins
arena showing the actual arena struct
tcache showing the state of tcache

and more...

For more info, also take a look at this interesting article: Tcache Keys
A primitive double-free protection.

That's an outstanding answer Marco, thank you for spending your time on this matter. Ive been looking for an excuse to dig further into the gdb gef/peda/pwndbg add-ins and now have the perfect excuse.

Following Marco's answer, I did some playing around with GLIBC_TUNABLES as follows:
(gdb) set environment GLIBC_TUNABLES glibc.malloc.tcache_count=0
(gdb) set environment GLIBC_TUNABLES glibc.malloc.mxfast=0

Disabling the tcache and fast bins as above give the behaviour that I expected in my original question, an unsorted bin in response to the free() call.

Nice one, I was unaware of the mxfast tunable.
